# PySide2 QT QWinEventNotifier strange ValueError

Tags: qt, pyside2, valueerror

The function that is supposed to accept int value is giving value error when explicit int is used.
The line producing error is:

```
self.m_notifier = QtCore.QWinEventNotifier() # << this is fine
self.m_notifier.setHandle( int(84) ) # << here
# self.m_notifier.setHandle( 84  ) # << this also does not work
```

Hard to be more explicit about using **int**, however in debug window on Win10 cmd I get feedback that I'm not actually using **int**:

```
ValueError: 'PySide2.QtCore.QWinEventNotifier.setHandle' called with wrong argument values:   
   PySide2.QtCore.QWinEventNotifier.setHandle(84,)     
Found signature:    
   PySide2.QtCore.QWinEventNotifier.setHandle(int)
```

Comment: Seems related to [this bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1756), but it's not resolved yet.

Comment: Sounds like it. I tried to google the problem but somehow didn't found the link you give. In any case seems it may be a bug in PySide and not only my local issue. Bad luck, wanted to add some features to my app...

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: My app works on Win and Lin. Running app from terminal and typing into can give an error, QT hanging. e.g. doing ctrl-c on selected text in terminal (somehow I thought ctrl-c should make a copy on selected text, not send a kill signal). So to protect the app from hanging I wanted to catch any signal and silence it on both OS's just in case. Notifier was supposed to work, but since it failed I've found using python signal is enough to block ctrl-c which may be sufficient (it is  easy to confuse "ctrl-c copy" with "ctrl-c kill signal" and other cases probably won't be needed).

Comment: Interaction from terminal is a very rare requirement for GUI programs, do you *actually* need that feature, or you're just worried that people may be doing unexpected things? In the Linux world the kill ctrl+c shortcut is fairly common knowledge, it's unlikely that the user would use it (and it's still possible to catch it, as you've found out). Note that this might not be enough for the (annoying) "feature" introduced in Windows 10 which halts the application whenever the user clicks on the prompt. But, again, if you're just worried about the user pressing the wrong keys, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: I used to run my app from terminal and doing prints for debug. One thing for sure this gave me unexpected strange errors and so to get rid of them and focus on actual functionality bugs I wanted to remove it at least for myself. Ctrl-c might be pretty annoying when occasionally forgetting about linux terminal ctrl-c :) Users may also run the app from source/terminal so for some cases they might have such bug (little probability though). I think the signal lib on python is a good enough fix at least to help myself. BTW which one signal on W10 halts the app?